# Fazer download usando o axios?

Tags: javascript, pdf, download, vue.js, axios

Estou usando o Axios para efetuar as requisições da minha aplicação, e em uma das requisições GET retorna um arquivo PDF. Quando faço a requisição GET pela Postman ele abre uma janela pra escolher onde salvar o arquivo, porém quando faço a requisição pelo minha aplicação ele não efetua o download. Qual método devo usar para baixar o arquivo??

```
axios.get('/server/pdfs')
.then(function (response) {
  //Qual método usar aqui para efetuar o download??
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error)
})
```

Já olhei a documentação oficial no GitHub e lá não explica como fazer download usando o Axios.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basta criar o arquivo com o `Blob` e passando o mime type. Depois abra um novo link passando a url encodada. Você também pode utilizar o link criado em itens do tipo `a` e `iframe`.

```
axios.get('/server/pdfs')
.then(function(response) {
    var blob = new Blob([response.data], {
          type: 'application/pdf'
    });
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    window.open(url);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error)
});
```

Comment: Após ter configurado a URL ele abriu o PDF quando foi feito a requisição, porém abriu outro PDF, não o mesmo que está retornando quando faço a requisição com o Postman, vou colocar aqui o meu código do servidor:
 
`app.get('/baixarpdf', function (req, res) {`
`
    let file = fs.createReadStream('C:/TestePDF/pdfs/teste2.pdf');
    let stat = fs.statSync('C:/TestePDF/pdfs/teste2.pdf');
    res.setHeader('Content-Length', stat.size);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=teste2.pdf');
    file.pipe(res);
})`

Comment: Ficou meio desconfigurado, a cada ´res´ declarade e a cada ´let´ é uma quebra de linha.
Agradeço muito sua ajuda Bruno

Comment: @LeonardoEbert, este código que postou no comentário é Node.js correto? Continua abrindo o mesmo arquivo?

Comment: O código acima é Node, quando eu faço a requisição pelo Postman abre o arquivo correto que está em uma pasta e que eu especifiquei o caminho, quando faço a requisição pelo meu cliente ele abre um PDF que ele cria na hora, com um nome aleatório tipo: e792586d-ffc2-49eb-8d0b-66e75b7effda,e esse "nome" sempre muda

Comment: Até dei uma olhada e comparei os requests do Postman e do meu cliente e vi que no Postman está configurado "contentType: 'application/pdf', enquando no meu cliente está configurado 'application/json, text/plain, */*'. Estou usando o Axios e não estou conseguindo configurar o header do meu cliente para 'application/pdf'